# How to create groups for in-app purchase monthly auto renewable multiple products in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

Say there are two groups. Suppose group A is having one product which enables user to purchase entire content of the app. It costs 14$. My app has list of Models' profiles user can buy and see. Buying group A, user can view all model's content in app. What about users who do not want to purchase entire app but to purchase some individual model's content? Prices for all models are same: 3$. How do I manage individual model purchasing? They all cannot be in the same group as Apple allows only one in-app products to run at a time in same group.

So I created same type of product in separate number of groups. They rejected my app saying that the products should be in the same group.
There will be only one in-app product needs to be created for purchasing entire content. But how about individual artist content product?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, give your application a separate architecture.
Say you have 2 groups as you said. Group A and Group B

Group A - costs 10$
Group B - costs 100$

Have an API call to your own server, after the purchase to notify what group the user has purchased. Now you have the power to understand or write logic, that the user falls under what? 
Group B can give separate unlocks for the same user, that you have to give the user to unlock about and sync with your server. 
Group A just unlocks a particular song/album that again user has to choose after the purchase, then you sync that with your server.

Anyways what I am saying is that keep the logic of what is purchased and what should be unlocked, open to the User after the purchase and then sync with your server to know about it.

I hope i understood your question and I guess this kind of architecture falls under Apple's guidelines and it shouldnt technically be rejected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you misunderstood my question. Suppose group A is having one product which enables user to purchase entire content of the app. It costs 14$. My app has list of Models' profiles user can buy and see. Buying group A, user can view all model's content in app. What about users who do not want to purchase entire app but to purchase some individual model's content? Prices for all models are same: 3$. How do I manage individual model purchasing? They all cannot be in the same group as Apple allows only one in-app products to run at a time in same group.

Comment: Yes I am saying that write this logic in your app server, after making the purchase. Make the in app purchases as ambigious as possible and make this logic in an API call after the purchase

Comment: so group B(individual Model content purchase) will have only one in-app product?

Comment: yes, now its upto your logic to understand which one was purchased, as you make the user select which one, and then identifying it by an API call with the productid maybe after selecting which model the user wants to unlock